# laravel Undefined variable: fetchdata (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\A3Solution\resources\views\A3View\view.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

when i want to remain same page after deleting data. But it show this error after deleting data. Data is deleted but not showing same page

alcontacts.blade.php

```
 @foreach($fetch as $row)
<tr>
  <!-- <th scope="row">1</th> -->
  <td>{{$row->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$row->exampleInputName}}</td>
  <td>{{$row->exampleInputEmail}}</td>
  <td>{{$row->exampleInputPhone}}</td>
  <td>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">edit</a>
  <a href="{{ URL::to('dlte/'.$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a>
  <a href="{{URL::to('fet')}}"class="btn btn-success">view</a>
</tr>
<tr>

@endforeach
```

controller.php

```
 public function fetchData(Request $request)
{
    $users = DB::table('infos')->get();
    return view('alcontacts')->with('fetch',$users);
}
public function delete($id)
{
    $users = DB::table('infos')->where('id',$id)->delete();
    return Redirect()->route('ct');
}

web.php
route::get('alctact',[InfoController::class,'alcontact'])->name('ct');
route::get('fet',[InfoController::class,'fetchData']);
route::get('dlte/{id}',[InfoController::class,'delete']);
```

Comment: Looks like your error is in `C:\xampp\htdocs\A3Solution\resources\views\A3View\view.blade.php`, can you include that file in your question?

Comment: Are you not using Models?

Comment: What's the code for the method `alcontact` on the InfoController? You need to pass $fetchData from this method to the view.